# Ruby on rails : memcached read value is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I've inherited a Rails project that looks like it's using memcached.

I have a controller, in one method I'm storing a value in the cache with:

```
 Rails.cache.write("key", @var)
```

in another method subsequently called in the same controller I read it back with:

```
@var = Rails.cache.read("key")
```

and the variable is nil.  Why is caching not working?
I've just started using ROR so there's a good chance it's something pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of things to check:

1. Have you enabled caching in your development environment?

   You didn't say which version of RoR you're using, however cache is not enabled by default on `development` environment.

   To enable it, set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in `config/environments/development.rb` file.
2. Have you started memcached server?

   If not, start it with `memcached -vv`

If your memcached server is down when you try to write into cache, the call to `Rails.cache.write` will return `false` and the subsequent call to `Rails.cache.read` will therefore return `nil`.